# Pick random member within a role on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using this very simple script to pick a random member of a discord:

```
import random

@bot.command(name='test')

async def random(ctx):
    users = ctx.guild.members
    user1 = choice(users)
    await ctx.send(f" The 5 Dino Discord Competition is {user1}! Congratulations")
```

This works perfectly well. But i need to pick just from members within a role. CTX.role.members does not appear to be a thing. So i have no clue how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the role using utils.get, which is a function of discord.py

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='role_name')
```

alternatively you could add an argument to the command, and then users have to mention a role or add the role id:

```py
async def random(ctx, role:discord.Role):
    #...
```

and then randomly choose a member from the role using

```py
random_member = random.choice(role.members)
```

---

### References

- [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [role.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.members)
- [guild.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)

Comment: whenever i use random.choice i always get the error Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'choice'

Comment: I edited random.choice(members) to choice(role.members) and it stopped throwing the error

Comment: Does it work now? If yes, could you accept the answer? The error you were getting is related to the way you import the modules which you didn't show @LegionOfBrad